# Does not setting @TransactionManagement default to CONTAINER?

Tags: ejb, java-ee-5

I encountered the problem that Mockito refuse to mock any Class with the annotation @TransactionManagement. Now I know that this annotation is not required if you want container managed transaction in jee6. Is this also the case in jee5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container managed transactions have been the default in EJB containers  since EJB 3.0 (part of Java EE 5). Prior to this you were required to specify the `transaction-type` as `Bean` or `Container` in the `ejb-jar.xml` deployment descriptor.

The javadoc for [javax.ejb.TransactionManagement](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TransactionManagement.html) states:

> If this annotation is not used, the bean is assumed to have container-managed transaction management.

Furthermore, §13.3.6 of the EJB-3.0 Specification also states:

> By default, a session bean or message-driven bean has container managed transaction demarcation if the transaction management type is not specified.

Comment: The JavaDoc you are referrering to is the jee7 version. If you checkout https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/TransactionManagement.html , you would see that the comment isn't there. This is what caused my confusion at the first place. Other than that, thanks for the reference to the specification

Comment: Yes - I realised that when I checked myself. Hence the second reference...